# Apache URL rewrite: remove index.php and query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a link, for example:

`https://test.com/index.php?code=myko`

I would like to turn it into:

`https://test.com/myko`

My best attempt so far is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?code=$1 [L]
```

All answers I could see so far deals with either removing index.php only, or handling the query string only in some fashion, and the above is the closest I could see so far, but is not working properly.

In the case above, it adds `index.php` as the code. I tried with $0, $1, etc.

Please assist in changing this via `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. I needed to add QSA in the square brackets at the end. So instead of:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?code=$1 [L]
```

I had to do:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?code=$1 [QSA,L]
```